# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't shutdown

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I am a Ubuntu newbie. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad S205 3 days ago. Installation and working is no problem but it doesn't power off on shutdown. Hard disk activity goes off but the fan and screen stays on. I have seen a few threads here that pointed out this issue. I tried some of the options that have worked for some users like using "shutodwn" and "poweroff" commands and installing certain updates. However, none of them worked for me (which is why I am posting this obviously). Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the command `init 0`

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. It persists still and can't find acpi in /etc/default/grub file

Comment: Try the methods given here: http://askubuntu.com/a/578155/216503

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command

```
shutdown -h
```

or

```
shutdown -P
```

where from man page:

```
-h     Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system.
-P     Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `shutdown` with the `-h` option:

```
shutdown -h now
```

However if your system halts it is still safe to switch it off with poweroff button.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem on my HP laptop. [Found the solution here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Fixing_reboot.2BAC8-shutdown_freezes). I think it will work for you too. After this change you should be able to shutdown normally.

1. Open terminal and run: `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. the text editor opens and loads the file. Find the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add reboot=bios to the end. It should result in something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"`
3. Save the file and go back to the terminal and run: `sudo update-grub`

After that, reboots and shutdowns should start working properly.

Comment: That didn't work either. I had even tried adding "acpi=force" to the same line as suggested on another post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed ubuntu with acpi=off option,
that option restrict system to shutdown,
check your grub and erase the code "acpi=off" and reboot, may be it will work.