# Why doesn't running "sudo shutdown now" shut down?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

When I issue the following:

```
sudo shutdown now
```

..my newly commissioned Ubuntu 14.04 server doesn't shut down. It stops with the following message:

```
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility
Give root password for maintenance:
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

If I type in the root password, the machine simply sits there at the shell prompt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restart /shutdown from a terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal) and duplicate of [What is the proper terminal-way to shutdown?](http://askubuntu.com/q/73696/283843)

Comment: Close voters: This is not a duplicate. While the questions are similar this one is asking about a specific command, the other a general way of shutting the machine down from the command-line.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Traditionally, the command `sudo shutdown now` will take you to the runlevel 1 (recovery mode); this will happen for both Upstart and SysV init.
To get what you want, i.e., to shut down the computer properly, you need to give the `-h` switch to `shutdown`.

One thing to note here is that `halt` will close all the processes, turn off the CPUs and return the control to a ROM monitor of the mainboard needing the user to press the power button to get the power supply turned off, whereas `poweroff` after turning off the CPUs will simply turn off the power supply resulting in a proper shutdown.

The `-h` switch of `shutdown` will either `halt` or `poweroff` the computer, the decision will be taken by the system although in Ubuntu I have seen that it would normally `poweroff` the machine. To be sure of that, you can use the `-P` switch with `shutdown` to `poweroff` the computer.

To summarize, here are the commands available to `poweroff` (**not** `halt`) a computer:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo shutdown -P now
sudo poweroff
sudo halt -p
sudo init 0
```

The `poweroff` and `halt` commands basically invoke `shutdown` (except for the `poweroff -f`). `sudo poweroff` and `sudo halt -p` are exactly like `sudo shutdown -P now`. The command `sudo init 0` will take you to the runlevel 0 (**shutdown**).

Now what if you want to shut down forcefully, i.e., you don't want to wait for processes to close normally? In that case you can use:

```
sudo poweroff -f
```

This will not use `shutdown`. Rather, it will invoke the [`reboot(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/reboot.2) system call (used for reboot, poweroff & halt) to power off the computer instantly.

Comment: Or, combine shutdown 'now' with 'poweroff': **`sudo shutdown -P now`**

Comment: What do you mean by "shutdown forcefully"? According to [a man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8), `-f` option just skips `fsck` on reboot. And according to Ubuntu's man page, there's no such option at all.

Comment: @Ruslan: Perhaps confusing it with `halt -f` / `poweroff -f`, which bypasses init and tells the kernel directly to cut power. That _is_ forceful.

Comment: @Ruslan: I have modified my answer.

Comment: My laptop thanks you!  I was actually hung up on this one and just always using the power button, but now I know!  The halt was keeping my system powered on, but the poweroff actually powers it off.  Many thanks!  :-)

Comment: @Terrance Glad i could help :)

Comment: @Terrance  What happen if I always shutdown   the pc with  this command   ?

Comment: @RGG I would recommend that you run `sync` before this command, as this command bypasses anything that might still be in cache.  `sync` will force cached writes to the disk, then you can power it off.

Comment: @Terrance Technically, that's _buffer_, not _cache_.

Comment: @Terrance my ubuntu machine not shutdown many times, Can i use `sync` and `sudo shutdown -h now` on rc0.d/K01script ?, Is this method is harmful ?

Comment: @RGG The command `sudo poweroff -f` bypasses all shutdown procedures and can be dangerous to data.

Comment: @RGG `sync` flushes the FS buffers, so that all the buffered data are written to the FS (disk in turn).

Comment: @Terrance ok it is dangerous but none of solution works  for multiple machine ! really I've bed exp. with  ubuntu  :(

Comment: @RGG This isn't even my answer.   I just commented on it.  This is heemayl's answer.  It helped out a laptop I was having problems with.

Comment: @Terrance Is there alternative or unique solution ?

Comment: @RGG This is getting out of hand. Please ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 18):

I'm pretty sure the correct command needs to contain the "-h" option (halt). Try this:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a legacy from the days when the physical machine couldn't power off by itself. For example, the halt command `sudo halt` terminates all programs and unloads almost everything from RAM, *ready* to be powered off. However, if you run `sudo halt -p`, it will do all that, then signal the system to power off, or in the case of the `shutdown` command, you need the `-a` option, I believe, though I personally use `halt`.

Comment: What happen if I always shutdown   the pc with  this command   ?

Answer (score 4):

```
systemctl poweroff -i
```

use this for all linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the following

```
sudo shutdown -a now
```

or to reboot immediately after shutdown

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Looking at the shutdown help option it doesn't list -a as a proper command, but I could have sworn a long time ago -a was abort or something like that. Anyways I've kept using that and it it has worked all these years, but it looks like shutdown -h now is the correct option.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the Windows command `shutdown /a`, which aborts a shutdown (equivalent to `shutdown -c` in Ubuntu).

Comment: @deltab Yeah that must be what I'm thinking of then. Strange that shutdown -a works for me though.