# Ubuntu shutdown freezes after suspend

Tags: suspend, shutdown, encryption, 15.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Acer Aspire V3, along with pre-installed Win8.1. During installation, I enabled /home encryption.
There is no problem with suspending laptop for the first time, but if I try to suspend it one more time or turn it off - it freezes. It seems to be connected with this encryption, since when I try "sudo shutdown now", terminal prints "Please enter passphrase for disk…". After giving right password, the problem disappears.

Comment: Change your title.

Comment: Perhaps it is encryption. It will be hard to determine for it probably happens with awake. Dunno but it might have something to do with this post [Why doesn't running “sudo shutdown now” shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown).

Comment: systemd-tty-ask-password-agent eliminates the problem  too. Can it be used automatically - I mean via dialog and so on?