# Shutdown command does nothing

Tags: shutdown

I can't shutdown my ubuntu 14.04 anymore.

```
# shutdown -h now
```

Nothing happens at all

```
# halt -h
# halt:Unable to execute shutdown: exec format error
```

Shutting down from gui just messes up the lightdm. After restarting the lightdm everything is normal again.

Important sidenotes:

I have issues other than that (hostnames cannot be resolved ), which imo are all trigged by my new Samsung SSD 850 Evo and waking up from suspend. It mounted everything read -only and after a manual shutdown those problems Started .

But firstly I wanna solve the shutdown issue

thx in advance

---

update: after running

```
dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf
```

for a felt 1 mio times, dns resolving works again.

The file ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf was missing, which again makes me think, some file might be missing for the shutdown command as well.

---

update 2:
as pointed to in the comments, the `init 0` and `init 6` command works.

Comment: Try "shutdown -P now "

Comment: @user1136340 please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal)

Comment: Thx. I tried that too. Just nothing happens.

Comment: @Ravan same as with the halt command
`poweroff: Unable to execute shutdown: Exec format error`

Comment: @user1136340 have you tried those four answers....in my previous comment .Ok,then try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown)

Comment: Why not use    sudo poweroff ?

Comment: Ah nice. The `init 6` (and most likely the `init 0` commands work too).  But I guess the shutdown command still would be better, mainly because of notifications. http://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown (oh no, markup troubles ;) )

@thebluesquirel that doesn't work

Comment: Just curious I've always used poweroff... Is poweroff used for something different?

Comment: [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown), so i guess so.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything, so I guess the shutdown script was corrupted. To fix it I did the following

```
# which shutdown
/sbin/shutdown
#  dpkg-query -S /sbin/shutdown
upstart: /sbin/shutdown
# apt-get install --reinstall upstart
```

and now it works again.

I guess the next thing is to find out, why those files get corrupted. Thx for the help

Comment: Sometimes the solution is tricky but easy :)