# constantly files corrupted after ssd and ram upgrade

Tags: ssd, ram, data-corruption

I have a ~5-year old ThinkPad x201 and it worked fine until I chose to update my ram and disk to now:

- description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous (according to `sudo lshw -class memory` (M471B5273CH0-CH9 and JM1333KSN-4G) 1334 MHhz)
- and samsung ssd 850 Evo

After this files especially files causing package errors, but also a git-repo are constantly being corrupted ([like so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664424/shutdown-command-does-nothing)).

I did one run of Memtest (my laptop is getting really hot, causing a shuthdown. So no overnight-runs) and the integred SMART test (from the Disk gnome-disk-utility), both passing.

What I would like to now, is how can I track down what's really going wrong. Could it be the new SSD, the ram, or maybe after 5-years the mainboard?

(I am using 14.04)

---

**update 21.9.**

I changed back to my old hdd and no file erros anymore. So I assume it's a hardware error. I am still curious, if there is a way to check this software-wise.

---

**update 28.12.**

I sent my ssd to Samsung, they did a erase with their smart-suite (they have linux version as well, but I couldn't get it to work). I reinstalled ubuntu, but a bit differently (lvm and encrypted). No file errors happend in a very short (meanwhile I got a new computer) usage period.

On a sidenote [this launchpad-bug](https://superuser.com/questions/950658/no-samsung-ssd-found) seems quite similar.

Comment: Can you test the SSD with another computer,maybe?

Comment: i got a new computer which I'm using right now, unfortunately I don't have time for that. I still updated the question (thought it will be forever unnoticed ;) )