# Dell Inspiron 15 5577 running 18.04 will not shut down

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell, shutdown, restart

Simply whenever I try to restart or power off the computer, it will freeze and stop responding, forcing me to hard shut it down. This happens any time I try to restart; random freezes also occur, which I have not been able to find out the cause of.

Comment: Have you tried running commands like `sudo poweroff` or `sudo reboot`?

Comment: sudo reboot works, sudo poweroff does not, it just freezes.

Comment: The following answer lists a bunch of commands you can use to power off the computer: https://askubuntu.com/a/578155/167115 Also, I have a Dell laptop and I think that I just needed to update to fix this problem: `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Additionally, how much swap space do you have? Sometimes swap space can impact shutdown and cause freezes.